# Slow InnoDB aggregation queries comparing to Postgresql

Tags: mysql

MySQL gurus

We have readonly dataset, which contains around 4 million rows. This dataset is represented as 1 InnoDB table with a bunch of indices, like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dim_users (
  ds varchar(10),
  user_id varchar(32),
  date_joined varchar(10),
  payer boolean,
  source varchar(12),
  country varchar(2),
  is1dayactive boolean,
  is7dayactive boolean,
  is28dayactive boolean,
  istest boolean
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
ALTER TABLE dim_users ADD INDEX (ds);
ALTER TABLE dim_users ADD INDEX (user_id);
ALTER TABLE dim_users ADD INDEX (date_joined);
ALTER TABLE dim_users ADD INDEX (source);
ALTER TABLE dim_users ADD INDEX (country);
```

MySQL8 is running on `Ubuntu 18.04` in servers.com provider on a cloud server with 8GB of RAM and swap turned off.

The database has default config, except

```
[mysqld]
innodb-buffer-pool-size=6G
read_only=1
```

The problem is that aggregation queries like `select count(*) from dim_users` or `select country,count(*) from dim_users group by 1 order by 1 desc;` take too much time (up to 12 seconds) comparing to default Postgres 11 setup on the same vhost.
Default psql11 performs the last query for less than 2 seconds.

We were trying to profile and analyze this request on MySQL:

**Explain:**

```
mysql> explain analyze select country,count(*) from dim_users group by 1 order by 1 desc;
+---------------+
| EXPLAIN
+---------------+
| -> Group aggregate: count(0)  (actual time=241.091..14777.679 rows=11 loops=1)
|    -> Index scan on dim_users using country (reverse)  (cost=430171.90 rows=4230924) (actual time=0.054..11940.166 rows=4228692 loops=1)
|
+---------------+
1 row in set (14.78 sec)
```

**Profile:**

```
mysql> SELECT SEQ,STATE,DURATION,SWAPS,SOURCE_FUNCTION,SOURCE_FILE,SOURCE_LINE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROFILING WHERE QUERY_ID=1;
+-----+--------------------------------+-----------+-------+-------------------------+----------------------+-------------+
| SEQ | STATE                          | DURATION  | SWAPS | SOURCE_FUNCTION         | SOURCE_FILE          | SOURCE_LINE |
+-----+--------------------------------+-----------+-------+-------------------------+----------------------+-------------+
|   2 | starting                       |  0.000115 |     0 | NULL                    | NULL                 |        NULL |
|   3 | Executing hook on transaction  |  0.000008 |     0 | launch_hook_trans_begin | rpl_handler.cc       |        1119 |
|   4 | starting                       |  0.000013 |     0 | launch_hook_trans_begin | rpl_handler.cc       |        1121 |
|   5 | checking permissions           |  0.000010 |     0 | check_access            | sql_authorization.cc |        2176 |
|   6 | Opening tables                 |  0.000050 |     0 | open_tables             | sql_base.cc          |        5591 |
|   7 | init                           |  0.000012 |     0 | execute                 | sql_select.cc        |         677 |
|   8 | System lock                    |  0.000020 |     0 | mysql_lock_tables       | lock.cc              |         331 |
|   9 | optimizing                     |  0.000007 |     0 | optimize                | sql_optimizer.cc     |         282 |
|  10 | statistics                     |  0.000046 |     0 | optimize                | sql_optimizer.cc     |         502 |
|  11 | preparing                      |  0.000035 |     0 | optimize                | sql_optimizer.cc     |         583 |
|  12 | executing                      | 13.552128 |     0 | ExecuteIteratorQuery    | sql_union.cc         |        1409 |
|  13 | end                            |  0.000037 |     0 | execute                 | sql_select.cc        |         730 |
|  14 | query end                      |  0.000008 |     0 | mysql_execute_command   | sql_parse.cc         |        4606 |
|  15 | waiting for handler commit     |  0.000018 |     0 | ha_commit_trans         | handler.cc           |        1589 |
|  16 | closing tables                 |  0.000015 |     0 | mysql_execute_command   | sql_parse.cc         |        4657 |
|  17 | freeing items                  |  0.000039 |     0 | mysql_parse             | sql_parse.cc         |        5330 |
|  18 | cleaning up                    |  0.000020 |     0 | dispatch_command        | sql_parse.cc         |        2184 |
+-----+--------------------------------+-----------+-------+-------------------------+----------------------+-------------+
```

As you can see, `group by` query takes ages to complete.

So, my questions are the following.

I've never been using MySQL before, my main DB has always been Postgresql for years and I don't know whether it's normal behaviour for this DB or not - it's very slow when we want to execute `group by` queries.

Otherwise, if I'm missing something very important here, eg DB or OS configuration, could you please give me a pieces of advice on how to properly setup MySQL for read only purposes.

Thank you!